# The module of polynomials over a ring is free?

Tags: polynomials, modules

Let $R$ be a given commutative ring, and $R[x]$ be the $R$-module of polynomials with coefficients in $R$. Is $R[x]$ free with basis $\lbrace x,x^2,... \rbrace$?

I don't think this particular basis will work since it can't generate the constant polynomials (i.e. polynomials of degree $0$). So I'm stuck on finding some element of $R$ that could be added to the above set which will make it a basis.

This leads me to a more general question. If we use the convention that $x^0=1$, we could simply use $\lbrace x^0,x,x^2,... \rbrace$ as a basis for $R[x]$. But this seems a bit strange to me. Does this imply that no matter which ring we take our polynomials over, the polynomial ring will always have a multiplicative identity by simply taking $x^0$ to be the identity polynomial?

Comment: Yes, $x^0 = 1$ is the multiplicative identity for $R\left[x\right]$ and the missing element in your basis.

Comment: If the ring would have no unit. What would be $x$ or $x^n$? (Remember the definition of polynomials via sequences!)

Comment: Interesting point, MooS. If $R$ has no identity then $x$ is not an $R$-linear combination, hence is not, strictly speaking, a polynomial. But is this a reason to assume $R$ must have a unit to talk about $R[x]$? Why can't this just mean that $x,x^2$, etc. simply don't have meaning in non-unital rings?